# Is there a way to source cron jobs from a file

Tags: linux, cron, ubuntu-12.04

One of our servers has around 20-25 different cron jobs scheduled on it. Usually, we periodically check-in the cron jobs to a file in the repo using `crontab -l > cron.jobs`

While bringing up a new server, which is a replica of the previous server (in terms of OS and deployed code base), is it possible to source the cron jobs for the new server from a file containing valid cron jobs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify a user name with system crontab files placed in `/etc/cron.d`, e.g.

```
* * * * * USERNAME COMMAND
```

The command `crontab -l` dumps current user's crontab without user name. If you want to re-use it you can import it under any user on a new system

```
crontab -u USER1 -l | ssh USER2@NEW_SYSTEM "crontab -u USER2 -"
```

Or copy the dump `cron.jobs` to this system

```
crontab -u USER1 -l > cron.jobs
crontab -u USER2 cron.jobs
```

Answer (score 1):

Just drop the file into `/etc/cron.d`.

Comment: Thanks! Your answer works, but doing `crontab < cron.jobs` was what I was looking for.

Comment: ansh0l, you should probably write that up as an answer and post it yourself; in a couple of days, the system will allow you to accept that one.  If that's really the answer you were looking for, then doing this is entirely within the spirit of SF, and correctly marks your answer as the one that most satisfied you for those who read this question in the future.

Comment: @MadHatter Thanks for the hat-tip. For now, I have marked another answer by dsumsky as the accepted answer.